# Displaying results through polygon tool on Leaflet map using event listeners

Tags: leaflet, geojson, angularjs, event-listener

I have certain documents residing on within my database. Currently i am able to display their Geojson on the map by drawing a polyogon within a certain area and then clicking on a button but i want to be able to do this whole process in such a way that if user creates a polygon on the map for query, it automatically returns the result without any button involved in between. which event handler should i be using for that?

**JS code**

```
angular.extend($scope, {
  center: {
    lat: 51.505,
    lng: 10.09,
    zoom: 3
  },
  controls: {
    scale:true,
    draw: {}

  },

  layers: {
    baselayers: {
      mapbox_light: {
        name: 'Mapbox Streets',
        url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicmVoYW5zNTE2IiwiYSI6ImNpeWxjcWNkODAwNGwzM3FxamR6a2gxOXkifQ.PuUfs90MyfmVGYVqx0AoUw',
        type: 'xyz',
        layerOptions: {
          apikey: 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmVoYW5zNTE2IiwiYSI6ImNpeWxjcWNkODAwNGwzM3FxamR6a2gxOXkifQ.PuUfs90MyfmVGYVqx0AoUw',
          mapid: 'mapbox.streets',
          format: '@2x.png'
        },
        layerParams: {
          showOnSelector: false
        }
      }
    },
    overlays: {
      draw: {
        name: 'draw',
        type: 'group',
        visible: true,
        layerParams: {
          showOnSelector: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});


leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {

  leafletData.getLayers().then(function(baselayers) {
    var drawnItems = baselayers.overlays.draw;

    map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
      var layer = e.layer;

      drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

      console.log(JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON()));
      coordinates_selected = layer.toGeoJSON();
    });
  });
});
```

**function fetching data from server**

```
function callingspatialsearch(){
  console.log('calling spatial search');
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  httpRequests.
  spatialsearch(coordinates_selected)
    .then(cb1)
    .catch(errorHandler);
  return deferred.promise;


  function cb1(response){
    $log.debug('result of search2: %o', response);
    var t= response.data.hits.hits;
    var c=[];
    for (var x in t){
      c.push(t[x]._source.metadata.o2r.spatial.geometry);
    }
    console.log(c,'response array');
    deferred.resolve(response);
    angular.extend($scope, {
      geojson: {
        data: c,
        style: {
          fillColor: "green",
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1,
          color: 'white',
          dashArray: '3',
          fillOpacity: 0.7
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function errorHandler(e){
    $log.debug('search error: %o', e);
    deferred.resolve(e);
  }

}
```

Comment: How are you letting users draw polygons? Leaflet.draw, Leaflet.editable, something else?

Comment: @IvanSanchez leaflet.draw

Comment: And have you read https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-event ?

Comment: @IvanSanchez yes i have gone through the docs. i am using `draw:created` currently in my code which i have added into the question but i am still not sure how to fetch the data automatically from server without any buttons invloved? i cannot figure out how and which event should be used for that?

Comment: You just fetch the data from the server inside the handler for the `draw:created` event.

Comment: @IvanSanchez i am fetching the data through a separate function which i have added in the question. How can i integrate both of them together to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the architecture of your code, the approach would be to call

httpRequests.spatialsearch(coordinates_selected)

inside the handler for the `draw:created` event, making sure that the coordinates are passed **and** ultimately used in the HTTP request, e.g.:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (ev) {
  httpRequests.spatialsearch(ev.layer.toGeoJson())
  .then(function(data){
    ...
  })

  ...
});
```

The way your code is written now makes it impossible to know the data that `httpRequests.spatialsearch()` expects as an input. Does it expect a GeoJSON `Feature`? A GeoJSON `Geometry`? Coordinates in a plain array? Pairs of coordinates in a nested array? A `Feature` is **not** a `Geometry` which is **not** a set of coordinates, and you should note (hint: use comments in your code) what each function expects as an input.

Comment: got it solved by just calling the function in `draw:created` handler.